# Uniformaly integrability of submartingale and stopped submartingale

Tags: probability-theory

I learnt a proposition on my probability course:

If $\{X_n\}$ is a uniformly integrable $(F_n)$ submartingale, and $T$ is a $(F_n)$ stopping time, then $X_{\min\{n,T\}}$ is uniformly integrable $(F_n)$ submartingale and $E(|X_T|)<\infty$.

I propose a proof:

Since $\{X_n\}$ is a uniform integrable $(F_n)$ submartingale and $T$ is a $(F_n)$ stopping time, we have $X_{\min\{n,T\}}$ is a $(F_n)$ submartingale (which is integrable).

Therefore, $E(|X_T|)\leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}E(|X_{\min\{n,T\}}|)<\infty$ by Fatou's lemma.

$\sup_n\int_{|X_{\min\{n,T\}}|>M}|X_{\min\{n,T\}}|dP\leq\int_{\{|X_T|>M}|X_T|dP+\sup_n\int_{|X_{n}|>M}|X_n|dP<\infty$ by Dominated convergence theorem and uniformly integrability of $X_n$.

(By DCT, $\int_{\{|X_T|>M}|X_T|dP\rightarrow 0$ as $M\rightarrow\infty$.)

My questions are:

1. Is this proof correct?
2. It seems that to show $X_T$ is integrable, we do not need $X_n$ is uniformly integrable.

Answer (score 0):

To answer 2), I believe you need to use the fact that $X_n$ is uniformly bounded to say that $\lim \inf E(|X_{\min\{n,T\}}|) < \infty$. I do this below following a template from my course. The rest looks good to me! You actually helped me for c), so thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]